# Is there a more specific name for this PDE and how do I solve it?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, online-resources

I have reduced a problem I am working on down to finding a solution $u: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ for a PDE of the form

$$u_t(t, x) + (a x  f(t)  + b) u(t, x) + (c x + d)u_x(t, x) = 0$$

where $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies some "niceness" properties.

I am not a PDE expert, so I searched online to see if this is a standard form for a PDE. I have found that this is a "[First-order partial differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_partial_differential_equation)" of dimension 2. [This section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_partial_differential_equation#Two-dimensional_theory) on the Wikipedia describes how to solves these PDEs in general, but I can't make sense of this section or figure out how to apply it to my PDE. I believe that this section may be too general for my needs, and that the problem I am solving may be fall into a more specific class of PDEs.

I believe that PDEs of this form will continue to show up frequently in the work I am doing, so: does a PDE of this form fall into a more specific category than "first-order partial differential equation of dimension 2," and how do I solve it?

Comment: You can add "linear" to your description.  For (even "nice") general function $f$, I doubt there is a closed-form solution.

Comment: This is just a first order linear equation and can be solved using characteristics.

Comment: More specifically, you can write the equation as $\partial_t u=...$ where $...$ involves only $u$ and its spacial derivatives. This is known as a "time evolution equation", and they have some known properties. They can often be solved using Fourier transform methods, or in the worst case, explicit time integration.

Comment: @GEdgar I am not a PDE expert. The engineering book I got this from (the book is not about PDEs) solved it by "guess and check" where $f$ appeared in part of the solution as $\int _{t_0} ^{t_1} f(t) \mathrm{d}t$.

Comment: @K.defaoite My original equation was of that form. I simplified it to this by taking the Fourier transform in the second dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$u_t(t, x) + (c x + d)u_x(t, x) = - (a x  f(t)  + b) u(t, x) $$
This is a quasi-linear first order PDE.

Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{cx+d}=\frac{du}{- (a x  f(t)  + b) u}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{cx+d}$ :
$$\left(x-\frac{d}{c}\right)e^{-ct}=C_1 $$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{du}{- (a x  f(t)  + b) u}$

$\frac{du}{u}+\left(a \left(C_1 e^{ct}+\frac{d}{c}\right)  f(t)  + b\right)dt=0$
$$u\:\exp\left(\int_0^t \left(a \left(C_1 e^{c\,\tau}+\frac{d}{c}\right)  f(\tau)  + b\right) d\tau \right)=C_2$$

$$u\:\exp\left(b\,t+a \,C_1\int_0^t e^{c\,\tau}  f(\tau)  d\tau 
+\frac{a\,d}{c}\int_0^t  f(\tau)  d\tau \right) =C_2$$
The general solution of the PDE on the form of implicit equation $C_2=\Phi(C_1)$ is :
$$u\:\exp\left(b\,t+a \,C_1\int_0^t e^{c\,\tau}  f(\tau)  d\tau 
+\frac{a\,d}{c}\int_0^t  f(\tau)  d\tau \right) =\Phi\left(e^{-ct}\left(x-\frac{d}{c}\right)\right)$$
$\Phi$ is an arbitrary function.
$$u(t,x)=\exp\left(-b\,t-a \,C_1\int_0^t e^{c\,\tau}  f(\tau)  d\tau 
-\frac{a\,d}{c}\int_0^t  f(\tau)  d\tau \right) \:\Phi\left(e^{-ct}\left(x-\frac{d}{c}\right)\right)$$

$$\boxed{u(t,x)=\exp\left(-b\,t-a \,e^{-ct}\left(x-\frac{d}{c}\right)\int_0^t e^{c\,\tau}  f(\tau)  d\tau 
-\frac{a\,d}{c}\int_0^t  f(\tau)  d\tau \right) \:\Phi\left(e^{-ct}\left(x-\frac{d}{c}\right)\right)}$$
The function $\Phi$ has to be determined if some initial condition is specified.